# What if git clone another branch into the same directory?

Tags: git

What will happen if I will clone another branch into the same directory? Will files mix or replaced?

**UPDATE**

I meant `git clone -b ...` command.

Comment: It sounds like you may be used to a system like Subversion, where branches reside in different directories in the filesystem. Git doesn't handle branches like that. You may be interested in the [Branching chapter of Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).

Answer (score 1):

You can not "clone" a "branch". You can clone a repository or checkout a branch.

If you checkout a branch, the versions of the files in this branch will overwrite those that are currently in your working directory.
If uncommited changes would be overwritten, git will warn you. If there are untracked files, that would be overwritten, git will warn you. And if there are untracked files, that would not been overwritten, they will persist.

If you clone a repo into your working directory, that will result in "nested" repositories. As far as I know, git can handle that, but I never tested it myself.

If you are not an experienced git user, I think you would be well advised not to clone a repo into an existing one.

Comment: You can indeed close another repository into a subdirectory of another repository. The formal way to use this feature is through [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). It's definitely not recommended if you're just a Git beginner though and you don't have a good idea about what you're doing. Even advanced users won't always use submodules (there are alternatives to this feature), because it does have its own disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

you can clone another branch when using submodules.

If you want to combine several branched togheter (merge) you can pull the required ones into your main branch and **YES** all the same files will be merged which mean that will not ne mixed or replace but merged.

Using clone -b will override the remote dewfault branch (Whats HEAD is pointing to) and will checkout the request branch as your local HEAD.