# What happens to a git repository when cloning another one into the same folder?

Tags: git

From other answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588392/what-if-git-clone-another-branch-into-the-same-directory) I learned that this results in a nested repository. How exactly does that look? Can one switch between them How does it work when they both have the same name?

I did this by mistake and it rather looks as if the original one was overwritten. The .gitignore is replaced and I see only the branches of the new repository while the files of the old one are shown in the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git clone` command *refuses to run* in an occupied directory.

The *default* `git clone` operation:

```
git clone <url>
```

*creates a new, empty directory* so that the new clone isn't using an occupied directory.  You can, however, write:

```
git clone <url> <path>
```

to tell `git clone` to use the specified *`path`*.  In this case, *`path`* must name an *existing, empty* directory or be able to be created *as* an empty directory.  The empty directory will be filled by `git clone`.  If the *`path`* argument names a directory that exists and is not empty, `git clone` refuses to run.

"Nested" repositories occur when the *working tree* of a normal, everyday repository contains a directory that is itself the working tree of another Git repository.

For instance, suppose you ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
```

to create `./git` as the working tree of a clone of the Git repository for Git, then:

```
cd git
```

to enter this working tree.  Inspecting the tree with "show hidden files" (e.g., `ls -A` on a Linux system), you'd see that there is a `.git` directory here.  This hidden `.git` directory contains the actual repository; the top level `git` that you did a `cd git` to get into holds the working tree.

If you now ran:

```
git clone <other-url> project
```

and created a new directory `project` within the working tree, running `ls -A project` or similar would show you that `project`, too, contains a `.git` directory.  The `project` directory is the working tree of this other repository.

Running `git add project` now (which will print a gigantic warning message), and then running `git commit`, would add a *gitlink* to the Git repository for Git.  The gitlink is half of a submodule.  The half that's missing at this point is the `.gitmodules` file, which `git submodule add` would have created, but running `git add project` didn't.  This is a fundamental mistake: the commit created at this point has what I like to call a "half-assed submodule" that cannot be used sensibly.  That's why `git add project` prints that gigantic warning message.  (It would probably be better if `git add project` refused to add it at all, really, but that would not be backwards-compatible, and the Git folks are very big on being backwards-compatible for decades at a time.)

Whatever your actual problem is, then, it's something you have not described properly here.